# Append character to a JSON generated in MS SQL 2017

Tags: json, sql-server

I am able to get a proper output in a JSON format with the following query. However I need to have a CR+LF character at the end of this string appended. So it detects end of line.

```
SELECT top 1 *  FROM customers FOR JSON auto, Root('Customers')
```

So the output should be something like `<JSON>CRLF`

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, as there's no sample data, but would it not simply be..?

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM customers
        FOR JSON auto, Root('Customers')) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
```